# What is the correct way to cancel query of a stateless session nhibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

What is the correct way to cancel query of a stateless session nhibernate? On a normal session you can use `Session.CancelQuery();`. This method is not available on a stateless sesssion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better way (if it solves your problems):

```
statelessSession.Query<Entity>().WithOptions(op => op.SetTimeout(15)).ToList();
```

where "15" is the maximum relevant timeout time (at the database level) for you current query.

Which is certainly not the same as CancelQuery.

In .NETCore+, the Thread.Abort () method was cut, and "timeout" its only way.

Comment: There is a issue open in the NHibernate repository:
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/809.
Track the solution.